# Pipe operator that returns a boolean valued observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm attempting to implement a method that returns a boolean valued observable that where the value is true if another observable contains a real value.  This is most of the implementation:

```
   /**
     * Observe changes to the values.
     * 
     * @param key 
     * @return An {@link Observable<boolean>} indicating whether the value exists.
     */
    public exists(key:string) {
        if (!this.subjects[key]) {
            throw new Error(`No subject exists for the key ${key}`);
        }
        return this.subjects[key].asObservable().pipe(???);
    }
```

Does an operator exist that will perform a `value != null` check?  Something like an `isDefined` operator?

Comment: `map(value => value != null)`?

Comment: That will definitely work.  I was hoping an operator existed that encapsulated that like "isDefined".

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(value => !!value)
```

There is no operator that coverts some value to boolean one.